# Animal population dataset

Tags: data-request, animals

Does anyone know where I can find animal population censuses or datasets with different types of animals? It's for a paper on a type of sampling called capture-recapture sampling.

Comment: Farm animals or wild animals?

Answer (score 1):

You can find below some datasets looking at animal populations, focusing on endangered species. I hope you find some of these useful.

- [Number of Species in Each IUCN Red List Category](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/johnharshith/number-of-species-in-each-iucn-red-list-category)
- [A dataset focusing on endangered snakes, also including their red
  list status](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kkhandekar/conservation-status-of-the-worlds-snakes)
- [A dataset focusing on endangered types of fish](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/harshithgupta/endangered-fish-data)
- [Also fish, but this time both endangered and common, focusing on the region of Sweden](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/codefantasy/list-of-fishes-found-in-sweden)